# Errrors when loading ubuntu

Tags: boot, dell, startup

Ubuntu 22.04
Dell latitude

When I boot up this flashes on the screen briefly.

```
[01.86885] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/nvme01p2: clean, 511745/15597568 files, 33342920/62383360
[3.609275] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[5.540630] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

Should I be worried?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be worried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are informative messages, not issues you need to fix.  You can safely ignore these if the system otherwise works.